# Magento 2.1 creating attribute through eavSetup gives incorrect data on attribute getData()

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, eav

I'm creating a catalog_product attribute programmatically;

```
        $attributeData = [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Default',
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'position' => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ];

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_test',
            $attributeData
        );
```

After that I'm doing a getData on my newly created attribute and the output completely differs from a 'normal' Magento attribute.

getData() on Magento 'tax_class_id':

```
array (size=42)
  'attribute_id' => string '265' (length=3)
  'entity_type_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'attribute_code' => string 'tax_class_id' (length=12)
  'attribute_model' => null
  'backend_model' => null
  'backend_type' => string 'int' (length=3)
  'backend_table' => null
  'frontend_model' => null
  'frontend_input' => string 'select' (length=6)
  'frontend_label' => string 'Tax Class' (length=9)
  'frontend_description' => null
  'frontend_class' => null
  'source_model' => string 'Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Product' (length=41)
  'is_required' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_user_defined' => string '0' (length=1)
  'default_value' => string '2' (length=1)
  'is_unique' => string '0' (length=1)
  'note' => null
  'is_important' => string '0' (length=1)
  'frontend_input_renderer' => null
  'is_global' => string '2' (length=1)
  'is_visible' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_searchable' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_filterable' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_comparable' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_visible_on_front' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_html_allowed_on_front' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_used_for_price_rules' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_filterable_in_search' => string '0' (length=1)
  'used_in_product_listing' => string '1' (length=1)
  'used_for_sort_by' => string '0' (length=1)
  'apply_to' => string 'simple,virtual,bundle,downloadable,configurable' (length=47)
  'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => string '0' (length=1)
  'position' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_used_for_promo_rules' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_required_in_admin_store' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_used_in_grid' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_visible_in_grid' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_filterable_in_grid' => string '1' (length=1)
  'search_weight' => string '1' (length=1)
  'additional_data' => null
```

getData() on my newly created attribute

```
array (size=3)
  'attribute_code' => string 'test_test' (length=20)
  'entity_type' => 
    object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type)[166]
      protected '_attributes' => null
      protected '_attributesBySet' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_sets' => null
      protected '_attributeFactory' => 
        object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory)[164]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_instanceName' => string '\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute' (length=35)
      protected '_attSetFactory' => 
        object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory)[163]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_instanceName' => string '\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set' (length=39)
      protected '_storeFactory' => 
        object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\StoreFactory)[162]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_instanceName' => string '\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Store' (length=31)
      protected '_universalFactory' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory)[123]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
      protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'core_abstract' (length=13)
      protected '_eventObject' => string 'object' (length=6)
      protected '_idFieldName' => string 'entity_type_id' (length=14)
      protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean false
      protected '_origData' => null
      protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
      protected '_resource' => null
      protected '_resourceCollection' => null
      protected '_resourceName' => string 'Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type' (length=43)
      protected '_collectionName' => string 'Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type\Collection' (length=54)
      protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
      protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
      protected '_isObjectNew' => null
      protected '_validatorBeforeSave' => null
      protected '_eventManager' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy)[167]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_instanceName' => string '\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager' (length=32)
          protected '_subject' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager)[286]
              ...
          protected '_isShared' => boolean true
          protected '_events' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_invoker' => null
          protected '_eventConfig' => null
      protected '_cacheManager' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy)[11]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_cache' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache)[125]
              ...
      protected '_registry' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Registry)[160]
          private '_registry' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      protected '_logger' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog)[151]
          protected 'name' => string 'main' (length=4)
          protected 'handlers' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'processors' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      protected '_appState' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\App\State)[9]
          protected '_appMode' => string 'developer' (length=9)
          protected '_isDownloader' => boolean false
          protected '_updateMode' => boolean false
          protected '_configScope' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope)[12]
              ...
          protected '_areaCode' => string 'admin' (length=5)
          protected '_isAreaCodeEmulated' => boolean false
      protected '_actionValidator' => 
        object(Magento\Framework\Model\ActionValidator\RemoveAction\Proxy)[168]
          protected '_objectManager' => 
            object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)[41]
              ...
          protected '_instanceName' => string '\Magento\Framework\Model\ActionValidator\RemoveAction' (length=53)
          protected '_subject' => null
          protected '_isShared' => boolean true
          protected 'registry' => null
          protected 'protectedModels' => null
      protected 'storedData' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_data' => 
        array (size=16)
          'entity_type_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'entity_type_code' => string 'catalog_product' (length=15)
          'entity_model' => string 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product' (length=43)
          'attribute_model' => string 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute' (length=49)
          'entity_table' => string 'catalog_product_entity' (length=22)
          'value_table_prefix' => null
          'entity_id_field' => null
          'is_data_sharing' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_sharing_key' => string 'default' (length=7)
          'default_attribute_set_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'increment_model' => null
          'increment_per_store' => string '0' (length=1)
          'increment_pad_length' => string '8' (length=1)
          'increment_pad_char' => string '0' (length=1)
          'additional_attribute_table' => string 'catalog_eav_attribute' (length=21)
          'entity_attribute_collection' => string 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection' (length=64)
  'entity_type_id' => string '4' (length=1)
```

I have already run the indexers after the creation of the new attribute but with no effect. The only thing that 'fixes' this is issue is saving the new attribute through the backend.

Does anyone know what I'm missing so I don't need to save the attribute manually...

Answer (score 3):

you can not get directly custom attribute value from getData()
you need to create object of collectionFactory and then using

```
$nickname = $this->customerRepository->getById($id)->getCustomAttribute('test_test');
```

you can get value of your custom created attribute.

Comment: Then why is everything working like normal after an eav cache flush ? My 'custom' attribute is the exact same as creating it through the backend.

Comment: Also I don't want the attribute from an EAV object (in your case a customer), I want the EAV attribute itself... more specifically the data on the EAV attribute object

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after creating catalog_product attributes programmatically you should always clear the eav cache.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
}

$this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType('eav');
```